# Transpose a table using Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

Below is my input `DataFrame`:

```
+------+-------+---+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|number|word   |ID |Name  |prd_1|prd_2|prd_3|prd_4|prd_5|prd_6|
+------+-------+---+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|1     |bat    |101|Naman |2    |3    |8    |4    |5    |10   |
|2     |abc    |102|Bhagat|3    |8    |7    |9    |8    |11   |
|3     |abcd   |103|Anchal|1    |9    |2    |3    |6    |12   |
|4     |abcde  |104|Dev   |8    |6    |9    |4    |5    |13   |
|3     |abcdef |105|PArul |2    |7    |8    |7    |3    |14   |
|1     |abcdefg|106|Vipul |3    |4    |2    |8    |4    |15   |
+------+-------+---+------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now I want to transpose `prd_1`, `prd_2`, `prd_3` into a single column say `col1` and `prd_4` ,`prd_5`, `prd_6` to `col2`.
Below is the expected output `DataFrame` I am looking for:

```
number|word   |ID |Name  |col1|col2|
+------+-------+---+------+----+----+
|1     |bat    |101|Naman |2   |4   |
|1     |bat    |101|Naman |3   |5   |
|1     |bat    |101|Naman |8   |10  |
|2     |abc    |102|Bhagat|3   |9   |
|2     |abc    |102|Bhagat|8   |8   |
|2     |abc    |102|Bhagat|7   |11  |
|3     |abcd   |103|Anchal|1   |3   |
|3     |abcd   |103|Anchal|9   |6   |
|3     |abcd   |103|Anchal|2   |12  |
```

This is what I tried:

```
val df2 = Seq(
        (1, "bat", 101, "Naman", 2, 3, 8, 4, 5,10),
        (2, "abc", 102, "Bhagat", 3, 8, 7, 9, 8,11),
        (3, "abcd", 103, "Anchal", 1, 9, 2, 3, 6,12),
        (4, "abcde", 104, "Dev", 8, 6, 9, 4, 5,13),
        (3, "abcdef", 105, "PArul", 2, 7, 8, 7, 3,14),
        (1, "abcdefg", 106, "Vipul", 3, 4, 2, 8, 4,15)
      ).toDF("number", "word", "ID", "Name", "prd_1", "prd_2", "prd_3", "prd_4", "prd_5","prd_6")
    val myArray1 = Array("prd_1","prd_2","prd_3")
      val myArray2 = Array("prd_4", "prd_5","prd_6")
     val testDf = df2
        .select(
          col("number"), col("word"), col("ID"), col("Name"),
          explode(array(myArray1.head,myArray1.tail:_*)).as("col1"),
          col("prd_6"),col("prd_4"),col("prd_5")
        )

    )
```

Explode function works only once in a select statement and using it in a consecutive select statement will create a lot of unnecessary rows and I want to use explode 7-8 times in a single select statement. Also, the count of columns which I want to merge in a single column will always remain the same.

Comment: Care to explain what you try to do without using the (overloaded) word "transpose"? What exactly are you trying to calculate in the output columns, `col1` and `col2`? (you don't want us to guess by going over the code, _do you?_)

Comment: I don't want to calculate anything. I just want to merge some columns into a single column. My Output Data Frame clearly tells what I want to achieve. Ramesh has got that right. I'll try his solution and will respond.

Comment: _"I just want to merge some columns into a single column."_ Why do you use `explode` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `zip` the `myArray1` and `myArray2` and then use the *zipped columNames* to create `structs` and collect the structs as `array` and `explode` the array column. finally you can use `.*` notation the split the struct columns into separate columns as

```
val zippedCols = myArray1.zip(myArray2)

val testDf = df2.withColumn("newCol", explode(array(zippedCols.map(cols => struct(col(cols._1).as("col1"), col(cols._2).as("col2"))):_*)))
  .select(col("number"), col("word"), col("ID"), col("Name"), col("newCol.*"))
```

which should give your desired output as

```
+------+-------+---+------+----+----+
|number|   word| ID|  Name|col1|col2|
+------+-------+---+------+----+----+
|     1|    bat|101| Naman|   2|   4|
|     1|    bat|101| Naman|   3|   5|
|     1|    bat|101| Naman|   8|  10|
|     2|    abc|102|Bhagat|   3|   9|
|     2|    abc|102|Bhagat|   8|   8|
|     2|    abc|102|Bhagat|   7|  11|
|     3|   abcd|103|Anchal|   1|   3|
|     3|   abcd|103|Anchal|   9|   6|
|     3|   abcd|103|Anchal|   2|  12|
|     4|  abcde|104|   Dev|   8|   4|
|     4|  abcde|104|   Dev|   6|   5|
|     4|  abcde|104|   Dev|   9|  13|
|     3| abcdef|105| PArul|   2|   7|
|     3| abcdef|105| PArul|   7|   3|
|     3| abcdef|105| PArul|   8|  14|
|     1|abcdefg|106| Vipul|   3|   8|
|     1|abcdefg|106| Vipul|   4|   4|
|     1|abcdefg|106| Vipul|   2|  15|
+------+-------+---+------+----+----+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using flatMap on the df

```
scala> val df2 = Seq(
     |         (1, "bat", 101, "Naman", 2, 3, 8, 4, 5,10),
     |         (2, "abc", 102, "Bhagat", 3, 8, 7, 9, 8,11),
     |         (3, "abcd", 103, "Anchal", 1, 9, 2, 3, 6,12),
     |         (4, "abcde", 104, "Dev", 8, 6, 9, 4, 5,13),
     |         (3, "abcdef", 105, "PArul", 2, 7, 8, 7, 3,14),
     |         (1, "abcdefg", 106, "Vipul", 3, 4, 2, 8, 4,15)
     |       ).toDF("number", "word", "ID", "Name", "prd_1", "prd_2", "prd_3", "prd_4", "prd_5","prd_6")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: int, word: string ... 8 more fields]

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- number: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- word: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prd_1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- prd_2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- prd_3: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- prd_4: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- prd_5: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- prd_6: integer (nullable = false)

scala> df2.flatMap( r => { (0 until 3).map( i => (r.getInt(0),r.getString(1),r.getInt(2),r.getString(3),r.getInt(4+i),r.getInt(7+i))) }).toDF("number", "word", "ID", "Name", "col1","col2").show(false)
+------+-------+---+------+----+----+
|number|word   |ID |Name  |col1|col2|
+------+-------+---+------+----+----+
|1     |bat    |101|Naman |2   |4   |
|1     |bat    |101|Naman |3   |5   |
|1     |bat    |101|Naman |8   |10  |
|2     |abc    |102|Bhagat|3   |9   |
|2     |abc    |102|Bhagat|8   |8   |
|2     |abc    |102|Bhagat|7   |11  |
|3     |abcd   |103|Anchal|1   |3   |
|3     |abcd   |103|Anchal|9   |6   |
|3     |abcd   |103|Anchal|2   |12  |
|4     |abcde  |104|Dev   |8   |4   |
|4     |abcde  |104|Dev   |6   |5   |
|4     |abcde  |104|Dev   |9   |13  |
|3     |abcdef |105|PArul |2   |7   |
|3     |abcdef |105|PArul |7   |3   |
|3     |abcdef |105|PArul |8   |14  |
|1     |abcdefg|106|Vipul |3   |8   |
|1     |abcdefg|106|Vipul |4   |4   |
|1     |abcdefg|106|Vipul |2   |15  |
+------+-------+---+------+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving it

```
val src_df=spark.read.option("header","true").csv("src file")
val mapped_df = src_df.groupBy(col("number"),col("word"),col("ID"),col("Name")).agg(collect_list(map($"prd_1",$"prd_4")) as "map_1",collect_list(map($"prd_2",$"prd_5")) as "map_2",collect_list(map($"prd_3",$"prd_6")) as "map_3")
def mergeUdf = udf((map1: Seq[Map[String, String]], map2: Seq[Map[String, String]],map3: Seq[Map[String, String]])=> map1.toList.flatten.toMap ++ map2.toList.flatten.toMap ++ map3.toList.flatten.toMap)
val new_df= mapped_df.withColumn("merged", mergeUdf(col("map_1"), col("map_2"),col("map_3"))).drop("map_1", "map_2","map_3")
new_df.select(col("number"),col("word"),col("ID"),col("Name"),explode($"merged")).show(false)
```